# Cannot generate hyphen

Tags: hyphenation

I am new to TEX and am using [scribtex](http://scribtex.com) as an online latex editor. My problem is that when I put hyphen in my text it sometimes appears and sometimes doesn't appear. What can be the reason for this and how do I fix this?

The code for example I am putting in is:

```
  \documentclass[12pt,oneside]{amsart}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \theoremstyle{plain}
  \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
  \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
  \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
  \theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
  \theoremstyle{remark}
  \newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
  \newcommand{\R}{{\mathbb R}}
  \newcommand{\nil}{\varnothing}
  \begin{document}
  Reissener–Nordstrom 
  Reissener – Nordstrom 
  \end{document}
```

​
The output I get is "ReissenerNordstrom Reissener Nordstrom" whereas I expect "Reissener-Nordstrom Reissener-Nordstrom".

Thanks

Comment: What kind of hyphenation are you talking about: manual discretionary hyphenation like `this\-is\-a\-long\-word` or even `\hyphenation{this-is-a-long-word}`? If so, these only appear when necessary. If you want them to appear *always*, you can just write them as-is in your text: `blah blah this-is-a-long-word blah blah`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Keep in mind that it is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass`.  Personally, I have often solved my own problems in the process of reducing the amount of code actually required to reproduce the problem.  So, if what is below does not answer the question for you, please create a MWE.

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented your suggestion. Can you now suggest what is going wrong?

Comment: @Shahab: see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you call a hyphen is the unicode character for a n-dash. You can see it with

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
[...]
```

I changed the first one to a hyphen to make the difference visible:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain why earlier in well known english words (such as momentum-tensor) the dash was appearing while it wasnt appearing for Reissener-Nordstrom.

Comment: that depends to your keyboard or to the online LaTeX compiler. It is possible that your double -- hyphens are converted into the unicode caracter by default. However, using an online compiler does't really make sense

Comment: What is the crucial ingredient here that made the dashes appear? I don't want to just blindly copy big chunks of code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hyphens are used for compound words like: `son-in-law`.  For number ranges use two dashes: `15--24`. Punctuation in sentences uses three dashes `---` such as this.  However, if you are in math mode then things are different as a dash is a minus sign. So, you need to use either `\hbox`, or `\mbox`, or `\text` (if you have `amsmath` pacakge loaded).

I just tied pasting the code below at http://scribtex.com, and the output PDF that I got seems to work fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Compound words like: daughter-in-law.\par
Number ranges: 15--24.\par
Punctuation in sentences---such as this.

\bigskip
However, in math mode, a dash gets treated as a minus sign:
$15-25$, $15--24$ 

So use \textbackslash mbox (or \textbackslash hbox) to get back to text mode:
$a \mbox{-} b$  $15 \mbox{--} 24$

\bigskip
or with `amsmath` you can also use `\textbackslash text`:
$a \text{-} b$  

$14 \text{--} 24$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I added the Reissener–Nordstrom and was unable to get the hyphen in your code as well.

Comment: Looks like you have to use a `--` in this case, but I don't know why.